# Oracle function compilation error PLS-00103 (Encountered the symbol "SELECT" ...)

Tags: oracle, syntax, plsql, compiler-errors, pls-00103

I receive the following error when I compile this function:

> Compilation errors for PROCEDURE INV.USP_MSC_MODIFICA_ESTADO
>
> ```
> Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
>  continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
> sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
> date <a string literal with character set specification>
> <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
> <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
> <an alternat    Line: 14    Text: IF SELECT TRUNC((SYSDATE) -TO_DATE(@FCH_GRABACION, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) From DUAL=1 THEN
> ```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "USP_MSC_MODIFICA_ESTADO" AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE
      CURSOR reservar IS
      SELECT
        id_reserva,
        fch_grabacion 
       FROM tb_msc_reserva
      WHERE to_date(to_char(fch_grabacion, 'dd/mm/yyyy')) = to_date(to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy')) - 1;
      id_reserva    VARCHAR2(50);
      fch_grabacion DATE;
    BEGIN
      OPEN reservar;
      FETCH reservar INTO id_reserva, fch_grabacion;

      IF SELECT TRUNC((SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(@fch_grabacion, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) FROM dual=1 THEN

      UPDATE inv.tb_msc_reserva t
      SET t.flg_estado = 'C'
      WHERE id_reserva = @id_reserva;
      COMMIT;
    END if;
    WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0)

    CLOSE RESERVAR;

  END;
```

Comment: Wow, this is just a big mess. Sorry.  This is not sql-server, so you may want to spend some time reading the [pl/sql documenation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm)

Comment: If `fch_grabacion` is a `date`, why are you doing a `to_char` and then a `to_date` on it?  Why are you doing the same thing on `sysdate`?  If your query already checks that the day portion of `fch_grabacion` is 1 day later than the day portion of `sysdate`, why do a separate `IF` statement to check it again?  If you wanted to do that, you don't need a `select` but the statement itself is pointless.  You don't use `@` to prefix local variables.  You don't want to use names for local variables that conflict with column names.  And you can do everything in a single `update` without looping.

Answer (score 0):

Franky speaking too many errors in the code. Cant Write them all.
Few mistakes:

1. Declare on line-4 not needed.
2. Too many Begin statements.
3. While(@@FETCH_STATUS=0) isnt used for loop termination. Use EXIT WHEN.
4. Missed the Loop beginning & End Loop[Assuming that You are using Loop as you are Cursor in stead of Select Into]

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "USP_MSC_MODIFICA_ESTADO"
   AS
   CURSOR reservar
   IS
   SELECT id_reserva, fch_grabacion
   FROM tb_msc_reserva
   WHERE TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (fch_grabacion, 'dd/mm/yyyy')) =
   TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
   - 1;

   id_reserva      VARCHAR2 (50);
   fch_grabacion   DATE;
   BEGIN
   OPEN reservar;

   FETCH reservar
   INTO id_reserva, fch_grabacion;

   LOOP
   IF (SELECT TRUNC (  (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE (@fch_grabacion, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
   FROM DUAL) = 1
   THEN
   UPDATE inv.tb_msc_reserva t
   SET t.flg_estado = 'C'
   WHERE id_reserva = @id_reserva;

   COMMIT;
   END IF;

   EXIT WHEN (@@fetch_status = 0);
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE reservar;
   END;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

i´m so sorry, but i´m really new in Oracle. I have change the code, but i keep reciving the same error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "USP_MSC_MODIFICA_ESTADO"
AS
CURSOR reservar
IS 
SELECT id_reserva, fch_grabacion
FROM tb_msc_reserva
WHERE to_date(FCH_GRABACION,'dd/mm/yyyy') =  to_date(SYSDATE,'dd/mm/yyyy')-  1;

reserva      VARCHAR2 (50);
fch_grabacion   DATE;
BEGIN
OPEN reservar;
FETCH reservar
INTO reserva, fch_grabacion;

LOOP
IF (SELECT TRUNC((SYSDATE) -TO_DATE(fch_grabacion, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))From DUAL=1)

THEN
UPDATE inv.tb_msc_reserva t
SET t.flg_estado = 'C'
WHERE id_reserva = reserva;

COMMIT;
END IF;

EXIT WHEN reservar%NOTFOUND ;
END LOOP;

CLOSE reservar;
END;
```

What i want to do, is to compare two dates (dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss). (Yesterday and today) If my registry have more than 24 hours, then ID_ESTADO='C'

I have the error here:

```
 IF (SELECT TRUNC((SYSDATE) -TO_DATE(fch_grabacion, 'DD/MM/YYYY  HH24:MI:SS'))   From DUAL=1)
```

the message:

```
 Compilation errors for PROCEDURE INV.USP_MSC_MODIFICA_ESTADO
Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of  the following:

  ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
  <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
  continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
  sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
  date <a string literal with character set specification>
  <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
  <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set  specification>
   <an alternat
 Line: 18
 Text: IF (SELECT TRUNC((SYSDATE) -TO_DATE(fch_grabacion, 'DD/MM/YYYY    HH24:MI:SS')) From DUAL=1)

 Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the   f       oollowing:

  . , @ ; for <an identifier>
  <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> group having intersect
  minus order partition start subpartition union where connect
  sample
Line: 18
Text: IF (SELECT TRUNC((SYSDATE) -TO_DATE(fch_grabacion, 'DD/MM/YYYY        HH24:MI:SS')) From DUAL=1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue with ur code is that u r using comparison with 1 inside the Select clause.
Ur Code:

```
IF (SELECT TRUNC((SYSDATE) -TO_DATE(fch_grabacion, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))From DUAL=1)
```

Corrected Code:

```
IF (SELECT TRUNC (  (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE (fch_grabacion, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) FROM DUAL) = 1
```

However, there are better ways to compare 24hrs time difference[i m confused here as in whether u mean 1day difference or exactly 24hrs difference]:
1.If you want to compare 24hrs:

```
IF TO_DATE (fch_grabacion, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') < (SYSDATE - 1)
```

2. If you want to compare 1d:

```
IF TO_DATE (fch_grabacion, 'DD/MM/YYYY') < TRUNC ((SYSDATE - 1))
```

Hope this helps. If it does. Dont forget to mark this answer accepted and upvote.[I can do with some extra rep :p]